# jQuery .next - Add a Class to next Element

Tags: jquery, html

i'm trying to change on click the class of the div's inside the container and create a loop. But with the .next selector the class is applied to all elements.

The jQuery-Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#link" ).click(function() {
        if ( $( ".inhalt" ).hasClass( "active" )) {
            if ( $( ".inhalt" ).last().hasClass( "active" )) {
                $( ".inhalt" ).removeClass('active');
                $( ".inhalt" ).first().addClass('active');
                return;
            }   
            $( ".inhalt" ).prev().removeClass('active');
            $( ".inhalt" ).next().addClass('active');
        }
        else {
            $( ".inhalt" ).first().addClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

The HTML:

```
<div id="container">
   <div class="inhalt"><a href="#">1</a> </div>
   <div class="inhalt"><a href="#">2</a> </div>
   <div class="inhalt"><a href="#">3</a> </div>
   <div class="inhalt"><a href="#">4</a> </div>
   <div class="inhalt"><a href="#">5</a> </div>
   <div class="inhalt"><a href="#">6</a> </div>
</div>
<div><a href="#" id="link">hier</a></div>
```

Thanks in advance for your help!
Alex

Comment: What should this be doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, you want the active class to cycle across your elements:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  var $inhalts = $('.inhalt'),
      index = null; // no active item yet

  $('#link').on('click', function() {
    if (index === null) {
      index = 0; // make the first one active
    } else {
      $inhalts.eq(index).removeClass('active'); // remove class from previous
      index = (index + 1) % $inhalts.length; // go to next item and wrap
    }
    $inhalts.eq(index).addClass('active');
  });
});
```

This code caches the list of items you want to apply the active class to and keeps an index of the last item that was active.

Algorithm:

- If there's no previously selected element, the index is set to the first item.
- Otherwise, remove the class of the current index and increment the index (making sure it wraps around)
- Apply the active class to the current index.

Comment: Wow thanks for this fast reply, this was exactly what i want. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$(function(){
    $('#link').click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
     if($('.active').length==0 || $('.active').next().length==0)
     {
         $('.active').removeClass('active');
         $('.inhalt:first').addClass('active');
     }
     else
     {
          $('.active').removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');
     }  

    });
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/h47cf/12/)**

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way - http://jsfiddle.net/jayblanchard/5x72x/

```
$('#link').click(function () {
    if ($('.inhalt').last().hasClass('active')) {
        $(".inhalt").removeClass('active');
        $(".inhalt").first().addClass('active');
    } else {
        $('.active').next('.inhalt').addClass('active');
        $('.active').first().removeClass('active');
    }
});
```

This method takes advantage of knowing where the active class is. The only thing that could be done to improve this is to determine if any of the div's had the active class and then add the active class to the first one if none had it.

EDIT: http://jsfiddle.net/jayblanchard/5x72x/1/ demonstrates testing for the class and adding to the first one if it doesn't exist.

```
$('#link').click(function () {
    if(!$('.inhalt').hasClass('active') ){
        $(".inhalt").first().addClass('active');
    } else if ($('.inhalt').last().hasClass('active')) {
        $(".inhalt").removeClass('active');
        $(".inhalt").first().addClass('active');
    } else {
        $('.active').next('.inhalt').addClass('active');
        $('.active').first().removeClass('active');
    }
});
```